# React Native iOS build failing

Tags: react-native, build

for some reason when I trying to build, and run my App I get a lot of errors

```
CompileC /Users/EcoSurvUser/Desktop/eco-surv/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/vlog_is_on.o /Users/EcoSurvUser/Desktop/eco-surv/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/src/vlog_is_on.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/EcoSurvUser/Desktop/eco-surv/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/utilities.o /Users/EcoSurvUser/Desktop/eco-surv/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/src/utilities.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ecosurv.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ecosurv.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

The fun part is that its working on my friends computer

UPDATE:

My ios/build/dinfo.plist looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LastAccessedDate</key>
    <date>2018-06-06T10:17:34Z</date>
    <key>WorkspacePath</key>
    <string>/Users/EcoSurvUser/Desktop/eco- 
    surv/ios/ecosurv.xcodeproj</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: `Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier`

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

You need to delete both ios,android and node module folder. Run the following commands

```
> npm install //to get the node module folder

> react-native upgrade //to get android and ios folder

> react-native link // for linking the libraries

> react-native run ios/android
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check you're Info.plist in ios/yourProjectName/info.plist to see if you have a CFBundlerIdentifier?

If everything is ok with the plits could you also run

```
sudo lsof -i :8081
```

If a result is found, for example :

```
node 7601 XXXX 23u IPv6 0xc6b249599e5f1169 0t0 TCP *:sunproxyadmin (LISTEN)
```

Kill the process

```
kill -9 7601
```

And try again :

```
react-native run-ios
```